# as.Date() R equivalent in Python

Tags: python, r, datetime

I'm trying to create a list of dates in Python.
In R I have a list of values from 1:14975 that each represent a day, I would then use `time_id <- as.Date(time_id, origin=" 1979-01-01", tz= "UTC")` to transform the values into dates. Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: Do you mean 1979, or 1970?

Comment: I meant 1979, does this matter?

Comment: @LunaPaluna I think Hong Ooi means that the Unix Epoch starts 1970, so it might have been a typo. And in this context could matter, because 'unix' [is the default origin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#using-the-origin-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas `pd.to_datetime()` makes what you want.

```
time_id = range(1, 14975)

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['dayID'] = pd.to_datetime(time_id, origin='1979-01-01', unit='D')
```

Comment: No need to materialize the range into a list, just pass the range generator object to `pd.to_datetime`. And if you ever really need to create a list from a range, calling `list(range(...))` works fine.

Comment: What would be the difference with: `pd.date_range(start = '1979-01-01', periods = len(time_data)).to_pydatetime().tolist()` ?

Comment: I think that for the task that you are looking for there is no difference between parse numbers to time series with `to_datetime()` or generate sequences of time spans with `date_range()`, because both are implementations of the Numpy datetime64 dtypes, however, `to_pydatetime()` does change a Pandas Series to a Numpy data time array, again, and then to a list. It's too redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar with the datetime module (though pandas matches the R API):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_id = [timedelta(days=x) + datetime(1970, 1, 1) for x in range(14975)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly

```r
time_id <- as.Date(1:14975, origin='1979-01-01', tz='UTC')
```

will make `time_id` a vector of [Date](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Dates) objects, which are intended to behave like integers with a Gregorian calendar representation. But which can have fractions which will be ignored in said representation, but not in calculations of means, additions and subtractions.

Strictly speaking, there is no such thing in Python. The main things in the `datetime` module are:

- date (a day on the calendar)
- datetime (a point on the timeline, that can either be naive, or have a timezone)
- timedelta (a difference between to points in time, not to be confused with a period, which can be thought of as a segment of the timeline)
- tzinfo (the offset (as a timedelta) from UTC, that can have a name like 'CET')

Given that dates have no time aspect to them, it is unclear to me what passing `tz='UTC'` to `as.Date` should mean.

If we take a Python list to be a rough equivalent to an R vector (some sequence that can be subscripted and sliced to get to its memebers). Then

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

origin = date(1979, 1, 1)
time_id = [origin + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(1,14975)]
```

will be semantically close to your R code. That is `sum(time_id)` will raise a TypeError and you have a sequence of a type that represents a date on the calendar.

If you want your data to show that they are in UTC, they need to be points in time:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
# timezone.utc is a convenient tzinfo
origin = datetime(1979, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
# origin will get a time of 00:00:00, or midnight on that date in
# the designated timezone
time_id = [origin + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(1, 14975)
```

When you are porting R code to Python, the [pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) package offers a performant DataFrame implementation that can do vectorized operations, like R does. Pandas takes its inspiration from R.

One way of getting what you're after would be:

```py
import pandas as pd

time_id: pd.DatetimeIndex  # typehint for clarity
time_id = pd.to_datetime(range(1, 14975), origin="1979-01-01", unit="D", utc=True)
```

The pandas [documentation on Time series/date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#overview) is a
good read, for getting to grips with the different time related concepts.

PS. at first I edited the other answers<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69092006/383793),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69092598/383793)</sup> to return UTC datetimes, instead of the timezone naive datetimes they do now. But the comment I was writing became a bit large and complex, so I decided to write another answer.